# If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2},$ prove a expression equal to $\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-1}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2},$ then prove that 
$$\frac{(1-\tan\frac{\alpha}{2})(1-\tan\frac{\beta}{2})(1-\tan\frac{\gamma}{2})}{(1+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2})(1+\tan\frac{\beta}{2})(1+\tan\frac{\gamma}{2})}=\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-1}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma}$$

---

$\frac{(1-\tan\frac{\alpha}{2})(1-\tan\frac{\beta}{2})(1-\tan\frac{\gamma}{2})}{(1+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2})(1+\tan\frac{\beta}{2})(1+\tan\frac{\gamma}{2})}$
$=\frac{1-\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}-\tan\frac{\beta}{2}-\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\beta}{2}+\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}-\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}}{1+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}+\tan\frac{\beta}{2}+\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\beta}{2}+\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}+\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}}$
I am stuck here.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1-\tan \frac{\alpha}2}{1+\tan \frac{\alpha}2}=\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}4-\tan \frac{\alpha}2}{1+\tan\frac{\pi}4\tan \frac{\alpha}2}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\alpha}2\right)$$

Comment: I got the answer,thanks.@Roman83.